# deal with input steps with jenkins-cli

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

We are migrating to jenkins 2 pipelines. 
Previously, we used to run jenkins jobs by jenkins-cli.

We designed our jobs to [run input steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) to get some informations. We can't use job parameters for that.

How can I deal with jenkins-cli to fill input parameters ?
Is an API exists to run jobs and fill parameters ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by filling parameters? Job parameters are just regular env.VARIABLENAME variables, aside from the use in the properties block. If you mean you want to add default parameters, you can do that in the properties block as well.

Comment: During my job I have a stage with this kind of code

 releaseInput = input id: 'Release', message: 'Informations de la releaser à créer', parameters: releaseParameters, submitterParameter: 'submitter'


This code is surround by a timeout

I want to interact with my job wich is paused for an input through jenkins-cli in order to fill values

Answer (score 0):

There's actually API for the input action. Please refer a curl command:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/job/pipeline/1/input/inputid/proceed \
--header "Authorization: Basic `echo -n admin:token | base64`" \
-X POST -d 'json={"parameter": [{"name": "name", "value": "bob"}, {"name": "age", "value": "12"}]}'
```

See also http://surenpi.com/blog/devops/jenkins/api/approve/.